# How to set and output the buffer contents php

Tags: php

I'am really very new to PHP.

I have this code:

```
<?php cms_loop('500');?>

<div class="item">
    <p class="contents"></p>
</div>

<?php cms_loop_end('500');?>
```

I want to output everything between cms_loop and cms_loop_end functions.

I do it this way:

```
function cms_loop($id){
    ob_start();
    echo ob_get_contents();
}
```

and

```
function cms_loop_end(){
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

But that's not working. Any help appreciated

Comment: What does the `500` represent here?

Comment: Calling `ob_get_contents()` inside that function makes no sense, since you haven't started any output at that point. Your HTML only comes after the function has finished executing. What are you trying to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: Unclear what "not working" actually means. What did you expect it to do, and what happened instead? As the above notes, the code doesn't appear to make much sense, so it's hard for us to second-guess your real intentions

Comment: @hppycoder 500 stays for the id I will save into a database at a later point

Comment: @ADyson in my dreams it should have returned the div of class item and the p with class contents

Comment: returned them where, exactly? It should just output them to the screen. But you wouldn't need any of the ob_ functions for that. If you simply remove all those, you'd be likely to see the HTML get output in the normal way. (Of course, it would be more obvious if there was some content in it, but if you examine the raw response to whatever request is triggering the PHP script, you should see it (once all the ob_ stuff is removed))

Comment: @ADyson I got the point. let's say it is a var $loopContents that I need

Comment: Give a clear example of what you mean. Where does that variable come from? Is it passed into your cms_loop function, perhaps? We need definable context, not vague propostions.

Comment: @ADyson I need a variable that will represent all the contents that was met between the 2 cms_loop and cms_loop_end functions

Comment: What for, exactly?

Comment: @ADyson this 2 functions represent a loop that I could not start building without the question being answered. I want to collect all the elements from this loop and echo the in the page for the normal user or let them be editable for an admin of the page

Comment: @ADyson I have functions like cms_p or cms_img or cms_link that I want to place inside and see if I can loop through them like as if there is not only one call but as many, as many loop iterations were set

Comment: `I want to collect all the elements from this loop and echo the in the page`...but if you just leave the elements as they are then (without the ob_ functions) they would automatically be echoed anyway.

Comment: Although...if you want the content to be editable though then you need to store that content in a database, then you can just fetch the content as a string and echo it wherever you want it. If you're trying you build a CMS you'll definitely need a database. Storing it in a file as you appear to be doing is not really the right approach. Maybe look into how other well-known open-source CMS systems do things.

Comment: @ADyson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598902/how-to-write-similar-functions-in-a-better-way this is what I have for now for example for h1

Comment: @ADyson the desired solution is I can loop through h1's and create and edit many of those in one page

Comment: @ADyson https://codepen.io/trueFalse24/pen/oNBqRdY active link

Comment: Sorry that doesn't really clarify anything. I cannot see what that code is supposed to be doing or how it relates to h1s or loops? I don't think your concept makes any sense. Either that or you can't communicate the idea clearly.

Comment: P.S. `I'am really very new to PHP`...I'd suggest that a CMS is really not the ideal topic for a beginner. I don't want to discourage you, but you should be realistic. Don't just try to build something cool straight away. Instead, study the fundamentals of the language, study programming techniques such as object-oriented code, databases, how the web works in depth, and study existing examples of CMS systems. When you've got the fundamental building blocks, and have practiced with exercises and smaller projects, then you might be ready to tackle something as complex as a CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find the working code:

```php
    <?php
    
    /**
     * Start buffering
     * @param $id
     */
    function cms_loop($id){
        ob_start();
    }
    
    /**
     * Output everything buffered
     */
    function cms_loop_end(){
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    ?>
    
    <?php cms_loop('500');?>
    
    <div class="item">
        <p class="contents">Hello from buffered content</p>
    </div>
    
    <?php cms_loop_end('500');?>
```

Please note that I removed the `echo ob_get_contents();` from your `cms_loop()` function.

**Demo:** https://onecompiler.com/php/3wuscawt7
*(There is an option to run without account)*

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to achieve some kind of template rendering as you apparently trying to render some piece of HTML for later use. For that to happen, PHP needs to be aware of that piece. In your example, though, both PHP and HTML co-exist side by side without either side having any knowledge about the other. Your HTML isn't part of PHP's realm yet.

Let's change that.

The piece of HTML you've given is often called a *partial*, i.e. something that's meant to be part of something bigger. Like a sidebar being a conceptual part of an index.html file, but not a physical one unless included:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <!-- Partial -->
    <?php include_once('sidebar.html') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So let's take a similar approach and factor out the HTML into its own file first:

```html
<div class="item">
    <p class="contents"></p>
</div>
```

**partial.html.php**

Now we need to find a way to transfer this piece of HTML into the realm of PHP. The simplest approach would be to read it and assign it to a variable:

```php
$html = file_get_contents('partial.html.php');
```

Let's get back to your function for a second, because now you could do:

```php
function cms_loop($html){ 

    echo $html;
}
```

I have taken `$id` off of the list of the function's parameters, mostly because of the following reasons:

- you don't read nor write to a database yet
- if you did, this would be the wrong place
- you don't use any variables in your template, so there's no need to pass any in

Though let's ponder the last one a bit. Wouldn't it be nice if we could pass data into our template, for example to dynamically change the classes we have assigned to both HTML elements?

It would most definitely be nice, and it's possible, too - what we need for that is just a little bit of output buffering. But first, let's change our template to meet our new needs:

```html
<div class="<?php echo $class_outer ?>">
    <p class="<?php echo $class_inner ?>"></p>
</div>
```

So we'll have to define both values up front. But we might end up with a lot more template variables once we get the hang of it, so let's best use an array as a container to store our current and any future values:

```php
$data = [

    'class_outer' => 'item', 
    'class_inner' => 'contents',
];
```

Next, we'll need some function to render our template with the values we just defined, so it'll need two parameters: The path to the template file and our data array. Also, we want it to return our rendered template. That said, it'll probably look like this:

```php
function render(string $template_path, array $data): string {

    if (!is_file($template_path)) {

        return false; // Or some better error handling
    }

    // Let's have some sugar in our templates: Import all indexes 
    // of our data array as variables into the current scope so 
    // they can easily be accessed by the template we're about to render.
    // 
    // In other words, we now have two new variables:
    // 
    // - $class_outer (extracted from $data['class_outer'])
    // - $class_inner (extracted from $data['class_inner'])
    // 
    // Cf. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php
    extract($data);

    // Start output buffering
    ob_start(); 

    // Render template
    include $template_path; // By including it, it has access to all 
                            // variables defined in the current scope, i.e.
                            // inside this very function - like the variables
                            // we just extracted from $data
                            
    $rendered = ob_get_contents(); // Assign all output to a variable, so we can return it.

    // End output buffering
    ob_end_clean();

    return $rendered;
}
```

Now, we can call that like:

```php
$rendered = render('templates/partial.html.php', $data);
```

Comment: Hey:) thanks for the reply but I only wanna get everything between the 2 loop functions I have. In this case this should be div of class item and p of class contents.

Comment: That's what I guessed - but you'll need a function like the one in my answer to do that. You don't have to use the data array, and you don't have to do anything advanced in the template files, but if you want to buffer some HTML (or any other output, for that matter) than that's the way you'd to go about it. You don't have to use anything file-based, you can just put your template (because that's what it is) is some variable. But as for the buffering, that will always have to happen the way depicted in my answer (in the main part of the `render()` function, that is).  Because...

Comment: ...right now, you're just switching between PHP and HTML.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will go back to basics as I dont really get the code. Would like to mark this an answer, but cannot do so, sorry:)

Comment: I've heavily revised my answer so you might get a better understanding about the issues at hand. BTW: Though ADyson is absolutely right about learning the fundamentals first, learning a bit about how to modularize your HTML (about how to template, that is) is a good starting point. As long as you don't try to write your own CMS ;-)  Regarding accepting my answer, this should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers